# Is this sentence symbolication correct? Predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Key:
B_ = _lives in Bangladesh C__ = *cooks for* d = Donald

My sentence:
Donald cooks for all but only those inhabitants of Bangladesh who do not cook for themselves.

My symbolization: $\forall x((Bx\to \forall y(Cyx)) \iff Cdx)$

Is this correct? The sentence is quite confusing. Thanks! :)

Comment: The order of evaluation of $\to$ and $\iff$ is not clear to me. However, the answer seems to be "no" in either of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You haven't captured the negation: to express $y$ does not cook for themself, is $\lnot Dyy$. $\forall y(Cyx)$ means that everybody cooks for $x$.

You should also think about people who do *not* live in Bangladesh: with your statement, Donald is very busy indeed: he cooks for everybody who does not live in Bangladesh. The natural language statement doesn't say anything about people who do not live in Bangladesh. So the overall structure should be $\forall x (Bx \to (\ldots \iff \ldots))$ not $\forall x ((Bx \to \ldots) \iff \ldots)$.

Comment: I think it can be written as : $\forall x( (Bx \to \neg Cxx) \iff Cdx)$ ?

Comment: The first part refers to inhabitants of Bangladesh who don't cook for themselves. $\forall x(Bx \to \neg Cxx)$

Comment: You are getting closer, but have another think about people who do not live in Bangladesh. For those people $Bx \to \lnot Cxx$ is true. Does Donald cook for them all?

Comment: $\forall x((Bx\to \neg Cxx) \iff ((Bx \to \neg Cxx) \to Cdx))$ So the second part will say all the conditions for Cdx to occur.

Comment: Did you read the second paragraph of my answer?

Comment: I did, please help I am totally clueless by this point.

Answer (score 0):

> Donald cooks for all but only those inhabitants of Bangladesh who do not cook for themselves.

No; there is no biconditional here.   Say: "Everyone, *except* inhabitants of Bangladesh who cook for themselves, will have Donald cook for them."